# Switching to a multi business account

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sfmc-business-unit

We are in a tricky situation with a customer regarding his initial Marketing Cloud license setup.

- The customer already has Salesforce CRM and is now planning to introduce Marketing Cloud.
- For the first year or so things can easily be handled with a single business unit.
- For the near future we already know that business units will be required to support territorial branches (managing data visibility is one major point here).
- Due to financial scaling constraints we can't start with a multi business unit account structure as business units come with a price tag that cannot be offset with marketing gains. The customer simply won't be able to scale and reorganize his internal organisation that fast.

Can we recommend the customer to start with a simple Corporate Edition account and add business later as the need arises?

What is your experience here? Would a later update to an account structure with multiple Salesforce connected business units cause "major" interruptions of live processes due to required refactoring of existing data structures and processes?

For now we can assume that business units can inherit the master BUs Marketing Cloud Connect setup and Multi-Org won't be needed.

Thanks a lot already for your insight!

Comment: This should help you -
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187251/marketing-cloud-business-unit-considerations?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I know the ins and outs of business unit structures with salesforce connection. I only never had to manage a switch from no business units to multiple business units. I somehow remember that multi BU accounts have a different backend architecture but I'm not sure how a change impacts live integrations and processes